# How to detect P-R interval from ECG signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

How can I detect P-R interval from an ECG signal using MATLAB ? Can anyone give me code or any steps to determine this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the P wave (s).
2. Find the QRS complex(es).
3. Pair up a QRS complex and its preceding P wave.  Make sure to avoid cases where there is a PVC or other abnormal beat in between.
4. Subtract the time of the P wave from the time of the R peak in the QRS complex.